# Selenium Webdriver: Entering text into text field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I enter text into the text field it gets removed.

Here is the code:

```
String barcode="0000000047166";

WebElement element_enter = _driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div-barcode']"));

element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div/div/input")).sendKeys("barcode");
```

Comment: `barcode` is a variable pass it like this `sendKeys(barcode)`

Comment: Use `sendKeys(barcode)` as @SubirKumarSao says; the `div-barcode` field probably has validation to remove invalid barcodes.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Agree with Subir Kumar Sao and Faiz.

```
element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div/div/input")).sendKeys(barcode);
```

Comment: i am doing by mentioned below code: 

element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div/div/input")).sendKeys(barcode);

but problem is that text gets removed automatically from the text field after entering.

Comment: what do u mean by "text gets removed automatically from the text field after entering" ?

Comment: text doesn't display in the text field by using mentioned above code. (text is enters into the text field and removes withing 3 to 5 seconds.)

Answer (score 9):

I had a case where I was entering text into a field after which the text would be removed automatically. Turned out it was due to some site functionality where you had to 
press the enter key after entering the text into the field. So, after sending your barcode text with sendKeys method, send 'enter' directly after it. Note that you will have to import the selenium Keys class. See my code below.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

String barcode="0000000047166";
WebElement element_enter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div-barcode']"));
element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath")).sendKeys(barcode);

element_enter.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); // this will result in the return key being pressed upon the text field
```

I hope it helps..

Comment: Yes,It did.Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, it sure helped me, when no other solution did.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//[@id='header']/div/div[3]/div/form/input[1]")).SendKeys("25025");
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be the JavaScript check for some valid condition.
Two things you can perform a/c to your requirements:

1. either check for the valid string-input in the text-box.
2. or set a loop against that text box to enter the value until you post the form/request.

```java
String barcode="0000000047166";

WebElement strLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div-barcode']"));
strLocator.sendKeys(barcode);
```