# i want to write in textefield using Maven and paulhammant (Selenium_java)

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium, maven

I  try to write  in the text field using selenium but an error has occurred"unexpected identifier "
w any help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyEuS.png)

Comment: @ Dina Kindly please add the the required snippet of code that what you have tried. So it will be helpful for everyone to check

Comment: what selector you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what selector you are using, but if it is the same input tag as visible in your snapshot then you can try the below code. [it is just a blind attempt].

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("firstname"))).sendKeys("whatever");
```

and in general, you can also use the below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("Whatever");
```

I believe you can take help from this thread -  [Selenium Webdriver: Entering text into text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137109/selenium-webdriver-entering-text-into-text-field)

Below is the full working code. for demonstration, I have only filled firstname and secondname. do like the ans if it helps.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        String myurl = "https://www.phptravels.net/register";

        driver.get(myurl);

        WebElement FirstName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                (By.xpath("//input[@name=\"firstname\"]")));
        FirstName.sendKeys("Dina");

        WebElement LastName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                (By.xpath("//input[@name=\"lastname\"]")));
        LastName.sendKeys("Hayden");

        System.out.println("Successfully Enter Value in the textbox.");
    }
}
```

Comment: but I wanna use angular thus,this is not support the  a angular

Comment: Please provide a URL so that I can check. What error you are getting if you execute the above code.?

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"firstname\"]")).sendKeys("Whatever");`

Comment: https://www.phptravels.net/register thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited my answer with full working code. The error which you are getting is because of you are working with angular before loading it. for more information please take help from the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044519/what-is-the-cause-for-angular-is-not-defined